# How do I disable tty for one user only using Sudoers.d file?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, tty

I need to disable tty for one user over SSH only. What should I put in a file that I will place in sudoers.d?

Answer (score 3):

The `sudoers` configuration file is the wrong place to disallow pseudo-terminal allocation for a user that logs in via SSH.

In you `sshd_config` you could add something like the following *to the end of the file*:

```
Match User bob
    PermitTTY no
```

This would allow `bob` to SSH to the host to execute commands, but not to start an interactive session. I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 1):

To control more precisely who can log on/ and who can't to your system you can use `/etc/security/access.conf`. For me it's great because I can allow access to machine to exact users from specified machines or networks.

See `man access.conf` to get to know more about this file.